# Danger to laptop due to fan malfunction even with cooling pad?

Tags: fan, laptop

My laptop fan makes noises that indicate to me that it is failing -- if I accident nudge it abruptly, it can become very noisy and even make a loud buzzing noise before it seems to shut off although the laptop itself continues to run.

The cooling pad I bought seems to increase the length of time before the internal fan turns on but the fan continues to run even though the laptop feels cooler than without the cooling pad.

Can I just ignore the malfunctioning internal fan or can a broken fan damage the laptop either due to heat damage (even though the laptop with the cooling pad feels ok) or some kind of mechanical damage from the fan blades?

I would like to simply disable the internal fan but there seems to be no way to do so and maybe that is a bad idea; but if it is a bad idea, eventually the fan will fail entirely I would guess and then I wonder if the laptop will no longer work, even with the cooling pad?

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop is designed so that the internal fan provides a specific airflow for cooling.  Laptop designers know that internal fans will fail eventually and so it's unlikely that anything terribly bad will happen if the fan stops working altogether, but it won't be good for the machine - it may slow down to reduce power or perhaps shut down completely if it overheats.  An external cooler will certainly help but it's not a replacement for the internal fan.  It may be worth getting the internal fan replaced as it's quite an important part of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is overloaded with junk if it runs a browser and email and the fan is working hard and is worn out.

I would get some repairs done with tuning the OS for leaner operation, and keep the batteries cool which wear out faster with heat as well as extend the life of e-caps.

- repair or oil fan but better to replace it , clean the inside of dust. this will extend the life.

It will run at 60’C on the CPU with full fan and perhaps shutdown at ‘70C so keep the cooler on it till you get it fixed, pronto.

If you get the OS tweaked (lean and mean) it should be able to run without fan until you play games or run a lot of tasks at once.

Answer (score 0):

The laptops internal fan is designed to draw heat away from the heatsink attached to the cpu, gpu and other components. It is directly attached and often thermally coupled.

The cooling pad is only cooling the external plastic and residual radiated heat from the heatsink. The air gap and plastic make it very inefficient. The internal parts will see temperatures they are not designed for. Best case is the cpu shuts off without harm. Worst case you cook something. Bga parts tend not to like that.

Fix the fan or look into buying a new laptop soon.